# Convert a string to seconds

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I need to write a function that converts the string-   “11:43:02.454” 
to the numbers of seconds  between 0:00:00 and this hour-
“11:43:02.454” .

For example,this is the calculation:-

2.454 + 60⋅43 + 60⋅60⋅11 = 42182.454

and that's the output

```
time_str_to_seconds("11:43:02.454") 
[1] 42182.45
```

Comment: What exactly is the expected answer?

Comment: and I can't use pacakges

Comment: If you can't use packages, please show your attempts to implement the function.

Comment: for example if i took this time-  "11:43:02.454" the ouput needs to be 42182.45 , because that's the time of seconds between 0:00:00-11:43:02.454

Comment: smells like homework

Comment: @NelsonGon I think you don't need to delete an answer based on whether the OP can/cannot use a package.  The post would be seen by everybody and it may help somebody in the future

Answer (score 1):

If one is open to using a non-base package, one can use `lubridate`:

```
lubridate::seconds(lubridate::hms("11:43:02.454"))
[1] "42182.454S"
```

Comment: I can't use pacakges.

Answer (score 1):

Used the function `as.POSIXct` to convert your string into a date/time object and subtract midnight from it.

```
t1<-as.POSIXct("11:43:02.454", "%H:%M:%OS", tz="UTC")
t0<-as.POSIXct("0:0:0", "%H:%M:%OS", tz="UTC")
difftime(t1, t0, units="secs")
#Time difference of 42182.45 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to interpret "and I can't use packages", so I'm assuming this implies you cannot use anything outside of `base R`.

So maybe something nice and convoluted like this? Also has the nice benefit (?) of putting everything (rather unnecessarily) into a `data frame`.

```
toSecondsConvert <- function(timeString){
  timeStringUnits <- c("hrs", "mins", "sec", "millisec")
  timeStringUnitsConvertMultiplier <- c(3600, 60, 1, 1/1000)
  timeStringSeparated <- base::strsplit(timeString, regex("[\\:\\.]"))
  timeStringDf <- data.frame(Units = timeStringUnits, Vals = as.numeric(unlist(timeStringSeparated)), Multipliers = timeStringUnitsConvertMultiplier, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  timeStringDf$ConvertedVals <- timeStringDf$Multipliers * timeStringDf$Vals
  timeInSeconds <- sum(timeStringDf$ConvertedVals)
  timeInSeconds
  print(timeInSeconds)
}

toSecondsConvert("11:00:00.000")
# [1] 39600
```